# Complex numbers and sequences

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is a question I came across in my Math textbook -

[image]

I have spent almost an hour on this and still can't work it out.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How far have you gotten? Have you shown that [3] is correct, for instance?

Comment: Oh... yeah. I got that. [6] is what I don't get.

Comment: @Justin: what have you tried?

Comment: @WillR - I have tried the first part of the answer and I've tried expanding (1 + z)^n. I don't know what to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding $(1+z)^n$, we get
$$
1 + \binom n1z + \binom n2z^2 + \cdots + \binom nnz^n
$$
Note that the sum we're after is exactly the imaginary part of this, by de Moivre's formula.

Let's raise the left-hand side of [3] to the power of $n$ as well, and see what we get, again using de Moivre's formula:
$$
2^n\cos^n\frac\theta2\left(\cos\frac{n\theta}2 + i\sin\frac{n\theta}2\right)
$$
Now you just compare imaginary parts, and you're done.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in complex numbers. Could you please extend the answer to include how you got the solution? Thank you.

Comment: @Justin Have you heard about de Moivre's formula?